# For loop javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have this php code for $i from 1 to 19:

```
<tr id=\"comment$i\"><td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\" style=\"color:black;\">COMMENTS</td></tr>

<tr id=\"hidden$i\" style=\"display: none;\"><td colspan=\"2\">FIRST COMMENT</td></tr>
```

I also have some javascript to change display of `hidden$i` when i click on `comment$i`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for (i = 0; i < 19; i++) { 
$("#comment" + i).click(function(){
    $("#hidden" + i).toggle();
});
}
});
```

Yet it is not working ... I must be failing to see something, i was wondering if you guys could help me out please.

Comment: maybe it is missing var for start, `for(var i...`

Comment: did you tried to user toogleSlide() instead?

Comment: Try this: `$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    $("#comment" + i).click((function(i) {
      return function() {
        $("#hidden" + i).toggle();
      }
    })(i));
  }
});` By the time click event is being fired, value of `i` will be _length-1_ hence it will always work on last element-> `id='hidden18'`

Comment: Do you strictly want to use 'for' loop. As you have included jQuery library you can easily achieve.

Comment: at first you state `for $i from 1 to 19:` ... then your javascript is `for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)` ... probably not THE problem, but it is A problem

Comment: As @JaromandaX said, and another thing you have to keep in mind is `Do you add your table rows dynamically?` or you can also say `Does the jquery click events really get binded to the #comments?`

Comment: @RayonDabre Perfect man, thx !!

Comment: @Jackymamouth, Cheers :)